# Comparing keybind Events tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a simple interface which turns blue whenever a user selects it and turns white whenever it is unselected via the mouse. I am unsure why my solution does not work. (The function is being fired correctly). i believe the if statement is at fault.

```
def ColorChange(event):
    if event.type == "Enter":
        FirstEntry.configure(bg="lightblue")
    elif event.type == "Leave":
        FirstEntry.configure(bg="white")
    else:
        pass

#Entry Boxes
FirstEntry=tk.Entry(interface,textvariable=inputedData,font=labelFont)
FirstEntry.grid(row=2,column=2,columnspan=2)
FirstEntry.bind("<Enter>",ColorChange)
FirstEntry.bind("<Leave>",ColorChange)
```

**Full Program**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Basic Interface")
interface=tk.Frame(root)
interface.configure(bg='white')
interface.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky='news')
interface.tkraise()
#Tkinter Variables
inputedData= tk.StringVar()
outputData= tk.StringVar()
#Define Functions
def Process(event):
    getData=inputedData.get()
    print(getData)
    outputData.set(getData)

    print(event.time)
    print(event.char)
    print(event.type)
    print(event.widget)
    print(event.x)
    print(event.y)

def ColorChange(event):
    if event.type == "Enter":
        FirstEntry.configure(bg="lightblue")
    elif event.type == "Leave":
        FirstEntry.configure(bg="white")
    else:
        pass



#Fonts
titleFont = Font(family="Arial", size="48")
labelFont = Font(family="Arial", size="24")
buttonFont = Font(family="Arial",size = "20")
#Labels
titleLabel=tk.Label(interface,text="Interface Title",fg="black",font=titleFont,bg='white')
titleLabel.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=5)
inputLabel=tk.Label(interface,text="Input Data: ",fg="black",font=labelFont,bg='white')
inputLabel.grid(row=2,column=1)
oLabel=tk.Label(interface,text="Output Data: ",fg="black",font=labelFont,bg='white')
oLabel.grid(row=3,column=1)
outputLabel=tk.Label(interface,textvariable=outputData,fg="black",font=labelFont,bg='white')
outputLabel.grid(row=3,column=2)
#Entry Boxes
FirstEntry=tk.Entry(interface,textvariable=inputedData,font=labelFont)
FirstEntry.grid(row=2,column=2,columnspan=2)
FirstEntry.bind("<Enter>",ColorChange)
FirstEntry.bind("<Leave>",ColorChange)

#Buttons
processButton=tk.Button(interface,text="Process",fg="black",font=buttonFont,bg='white')
processButton.bind("<Leave>",Process)
processButton.grid(row=4,column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

For those asking for a reproducible example, here it is

Comment: Can you post a complete reproducable example?

Comment: @Erich Have provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `event.type` is returning a `tkinter.EventType`, not a string directly,

it looks like `<EventType.Enter: '7'>`.

There are two ways to get it to work:

Change the `EventType` key to a `string`:

```
def ColorChange(event):
    if str(event.type) == "Enter":
        FirstEntry.configure(bg="lightblue")
    elif str(event.type) == "Leave":
        FirstEntry.configure(bg="white")
    else:
        pass
```

Or use the `tkinter.EventType` as the value:

```
def ColorChange(event):
    if event.type == tk.EventType.Enter:
        FirstEntry.configure(bg="lightblue")
    elif event.type == tk.EventType.Leave:
        FirstEntry.configure(bg="white")
    else:
        pass
```

Either will work:

```
import tkinter as tk

def ColorChange(event):
    if str(event.type) == "Enter":
        FirstEntry.configure(bg="lightblue")
    elif str(event.type) == "Leave":
        FirstEntry.configure(bg="white")
    else:
        pass

interface = tk.Tk()

inputedData = tk.StringVar()

#Entry Boxes
FirstEntry=tk.Entry(interface,textvariable=inputedData) # ,font=labelFont)
FirstEntry.grid(row=2,column=2,columnspan=2)
FirstEntry.bind("<Enter>",ColorChange)
FirstEntry.bind("<Leave>",ColorChange)

interface.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the event.type is of type `<enum 'EventType'>` which is not a stright up string, so the equality will fail. Instead try:

```
if str(event.type) == 'Enter':
```

or

```
if int(event.type) == 7:
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, Python 3.8.7 ([release notes](https://docs.python.org/release/3.8.7/whatsnew/changelog.html)) has changed how `str()` works on tkinter event types:

> [bpo-41831](https://bugs.python.org/issue41831): `str()` for the `type` attribute of the `tkinter.Event` object always returns now the numeric code returned by Tk instead of the name of the event type.

[tgikal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4777984/tgikal) solution works even with Python 3.8.7:

```py
if event.type == tk.EventType.Enter:
    # Do something
elif event.type == tk.EventType.Leave:
    # Do something else
else:
    pass
```

Also, [figbeam's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172933/figbeam) solution above works too, if you compare `event.type` to a string version of the event numeric code or cast `event.type` to an `int`, but these are not as intuitive:

```py
# Compare string version
if event.type == "7":
    # Do something
elif event.type == "8":
    # Do something else
else:
    pass


# Compare integer version
if int(event.type) == 7:
    # Do something
elif int(event.type) == 8:
    # Do something else
else:
    pass
```